# How to disable Nagle algorithm in Azure queue with azure-sdk-for-python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage-queues

I'am using Azure queues, and I wanted to know how can I disable Nagle algorithm with azure-sdk-for-python. Is there a param that permit to do that easily ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In .NET it isn't a function of the client library as it is set through System.Net.ServicePointManager. This article seems to talk to challenges doing the same with Python:[Disabling nagle in python: how to do it the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404376/disabling-nagle-in-python-how-to-do-it-the-right-way). Maybe someone with more Python expertise than I have can weigh in?